# JavaScript "\8" literal

Tags: javascript, specifications

I am writing JavaScript to Python translator and "\8" and "\9" are causing me lot's of problems. According to the documentation something like "\8" or "\9" is illegal since they are not valid octal escapes. [Esprima parser](http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html) throws exception on such literal. However JS engines they seem to allow them and they evaluate to "8" and "9" respectively.

Therefore:

```
/\8/.exec("\8") 
RegExp('\\8').exec('\8')
/\8/.exec("8") 
RegExp('\\8').exec('8')
```

Should all return a match since /\8/ should be the same as /8/. However the results are inconsistent across JS engines and some return a match while others don't (for example Safari's).

What's the reason for all these differences? And what is the right way - how to handle other cases involving these literals?

Comment: JS engines in browsers are very lenient, (sometimes too lenient for their own good), because keep on running is a feature. Transpilers are much less lenient, because catching errors is a feature.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. What exactly do you expect to match and what did you expect to not match?

Comment: The problem is that I have no idea whether they should match or not, because according to the specification these statements are illegal but they are allowed in Js Engines and therefore some of my unit tests fail. So I am looking for more information on how to handle these cases.

Comment: @PiotrDabkowski: A link to the specification might be helpful?

Comment: Why not make a decision if you're working by engines or by spec?

Comment: Yes but the problem is when I don't follow specs then I don't know what internal values should be and this may cause problems with other constructs like /\8/.source - should it be '\8' or maybe '8'. So I was wondering whether somebody knows whats the general way to handle them properly. I can reverse engineer what V8 is doing in the background but that would take time.

Comment: "*when I don't follow specs then I don't know what internal values should be*". Just follow the spec, then. Don't rely on undocumented extensions done by implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You're right that the spec does not allow for it](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-additional-syntax-string-literals) but no one ever said that JS engines are perfect.

The "right" way to handle those cases is to report them as a syntax error, given that this isn't valid in JS nor Python*.

*As far as I know. I don't write a lot of Python but a quick [Googling](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) seems to indicate it isn't.

Comment: @apsillers True, but [as you see here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#table-34) single digit octal escapes aren't included in the "modern" spec, only supported as legacy sequences.

Comment: Yes, immediately after the posting I realized the specific relevance of the appendix to this question (i.e., the appendix *does* allow escaped numerals but *only* if they are strictly less than `8`).